# How to use / refer to the negation of a boolean function in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use the negation of a boolean function in Scala, such as:

```
def someFunction(x: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = 
    someOtherFunction(x, !p)
```

But I get the error:

```
 value unary_! is not a member of Int => Boolean
```

How can I refer to the negation of p?

Comment: Coursera Course ;) :D

Comment: cousera scala class mate  :)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The negation of `p` is a function that applies `p` to its argument and negates the result.

```
x => !p(x)
```

If you want to be able to write `!p` or `p && q` you can use [this library](https://github.com/wheaties/Predicates), which pimps functions that return a bool with various logical operators.

Comment: It looks like a nice library, however I have a constraint that prevents the use of such a library: I'm trying to complete one of the assignments of Prof. Odersky's Scala Coursera class and I'm stuk at this point becase I can't simply pass the negation of the p function to another function. Is it impossible to do it in plain Scala?

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding, you are right. I accept your answer as it is.

Comment: @Emre, it's possible, yes. Can I assume you are stuck on the 'exists' question?

Comment: Hey Kim it works of course, but I can't understand this syntax though (newbie here), probably because of type inference...I'll try with the extended version:
`(x: Int) => Boolean = !p(x)`
Is this the same thing?

Answer (score 23):

Shortest negation of p: **!p(_)**

When you apply the predicate *p* as an argument to another function:

- p or p(_) are abbreviations of the lambda expresion: (x) => p(x)
- !p(_) is an abbreviation of the lambda expresion: (x) => !p(x) and with only !p the compiler gets lost.

For example, using a Set of integers (try it on a Scala worksheet):

```
  def someOtherFunction (x: Set[Int], p: Int => Boolean):Boolean = x.forall(p)
  def someFunction(x: Set[Int], p: Int => Boolean): Boolean =
    someOtherFunction(x, !p(_))

  val x = Set(1,2,3)
  var p: Int => Boolean = (_ > 0)
  //_ > 0 is an abbreviaton of (x) => x > 0

  someFunction(x, p)        //false
  someOtherFunction(x, p)   //true

  p = _ > 1
  someFunction(x, p)        //false
  someOtherFunction(x, p)   //false

  p = _ > 3
  someFunction(x, p)        //true
  someOtherFunction(x, p)   //false
  println
```

Comment: I appended println because on my Scala Eclipse I can't evaluate a worksheet if the last sentence has an in-line comment.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to solve it without the use of an anonym function is to define a concrete function for this task.

```
def even(x:Int):Boolean = x%2==0
def not(f: Int => Boolean): Int => Boolean = !f(_)
def odd = not(even)
odd(1) // true
odd(2) // false
```

You can also define ! yourself

```
def even: Int => Boolean = _%2==0
implicit def bangy(f: Int => Boolean) = new { def unary_! : Int => Boolean = !f(_) }
def odd = !even
odd(1) // true
odd(2) // false
```

but this only seems to works for functions of type Int=>Boolean, and not (Int)=>Boolean. The not(even) solution works with both.

Answer (score 2):

Istador's proposed `not` function works well, but I think we can do even better with polymorphism accomplished through generics!

```
def not[T](f: T => Boolean): T => Boolean = x => !f(x)
```

Then we can use it for `Int => Boolean` functions like `isEven`

```
def isEven(x: Int): Boolean = x % 2 == 0

val numbers = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

val evens = numbers filter isEven
val odds = numbers filter not(isEven _)

// if you actually wanted both, use partition instead
// val (evens2, odds2) = numbers partition isEven
```

And *also* use it for a `String => Boolean` function like this:

```
def startsWith(prefix: String)(text: String) = text.startsWith(prefix)

val fruits = List("apple", "banana", "cranberry")

val bFruits = fruits filter startsWith("b")
val notBFruits = fruits filter not(startsWith("b"))
```

A bit contrived, but honestly I'm not sure why that polymorphic `not` function isn't built into the standard library?

BTW, I'm taking Professor Odersky's Scala class on Coursera, too!