# Scala — negation of a predicate

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use / refer to the negation of a boolean function in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681616/how-to-use-refer-to-the-negation-of-a-boolean-function-in-scala)

I'm currently taking Martin Odersky's Scala course in coursera. In one of the assignments, I need to work with the negation of a function (which represents a predicate).

```
def fun1 (p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = {
/* some code here */
}
```

Assume the function literal `p: Int => Boolean` represents some kind of a predicate like `x => x > 0`

```
def fun2 (p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = {
val x = fun1 (p)
val y = ???
/* How can I call the negation of the predicate 'p' here? */
return x && y
}
```

For example, If I call `fun2` as `fun2 (x => x > 0)`

I gave it a lot of thought, but I'm not making any progress with it. I'm not asking for the solution to any of the assignment problems (I'm sticking to the honor code, I believe), but any explanation of what I'm missing here will be of great help.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681616/how-to-use-refer-to-the-negation-of-a-boolean-function-in-scala

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to write a function that takes a predicate as argument and returns another predicate.

```
def negate(pred: Int => Boolean): Int => Boolean =
  (x: Int) => !pred(x)
```

Comment: def negate(pred: Int => Boolean): Int => Boolean =
  (x: Int) => !pred(x)